# In Javascript, how to switch from value A to B and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, math, switch-statement

my goal is:

```
var a = 6;
switch(a)
{
    case 6 : a = 4; break;
    case 4 : a = 6; break;
}
// "a" is 4 now.
switch(a)
{
    case 6 : a = 4; break;
    case 4 : a = 6; break;
}
// "a" is again 6
```

but it's soo lame. How to change a value from 6 to 4 and back, with the same one-liner operation?

Answer (score 2):

Yhere are lots of different ways of toggling a value. But if you want a one-liner, then all I can thing of is...

```
 a = a==4 ? 6 : 4;
```

Comment: ummm, maybe without IF? I forgot to say that if "switch" is lame, then conditionals too :)

Answer (score 2):

what about others values for a ?

```js
a = a==4 ? 6 : a==6 ? 4 : a;
```

Answer (score 1):

With a ternary operator

a === 6 ? 4 : 6;

Got another idea (since you want to avoid the ifs):

You could swap the variable. Might be good if you need to do so, in one liner.

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
[a, b] = [b, a]; 

console.log(a, b);
```

When can do this from ES6 Destructuring. This way you "switch" your variable without any if. But you need two variables, so it might be better or worst, it depends.

Comment: ummm, maybe without IF? I forgot to say that if "switch" is lame, then conditionals too :)

Comment: without a check? no way.
Logically we could use a boolean and always re-assign it to the opposite:
"boolean = !boolean".
But then you might have to convert the boolean to your required number, so there is no point, better with the ternary expression as in the answer.

Of course, if you can use the boolean, reassignment is faster than ifs (if/else, switch, ternary - doesn't matter)